# Use jquery in juqeryUI tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am loading a file in JQueryUI tabs, when I include the jquery file in the called file i am getting errors while switching tabs, I thought its due to conflict of the jquery as it is included in both calling and called files, the problem was solved when I removed the link from the called file. Now the file is loaded in tab, well I have something like few jquery operations to be done in that tab, as the jquery is not included I am unable to perform any stuff in that tab, what is the solution, how did they design those tabs so that a user cant include the main jquery file in all the ajax called files. Is there a solution or this is a bug or shall i give up using jqueryUI tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the tab is part of the main page, which has jQuery in it. So you can select elements from the tab and call jQuery methods on them as if they were part of the main page. In fact, by the time you are able to call jQuery methods on anything on the page, i.e. after document.ready, it is part of the main page.

If you couldn't use jQuery with jQuery UI, you wouldn't be able to use jQuery UI, because that itself uses jQuery...

Comment: You mean I should write down the javascript functions of the called file in the current page

Comment: Ya I moved all my jscripts to main file and is solved. Thansk